# Swing component which is always on top - alternative to JPopupMenu

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to create a custom combo box component but I've been having difficulty triggering the visibility of the popup. What other component (other than `JPopupMenu`) can I use to display the combo box's items regardless of the size of the container of the combo box?

I've been trying to work my way through the source for `JComboBox`, but I can't seem to figure out how they show / hide the popup.

How can I do this?

Comment: -1, No need to clutter the forum by reposting your question. You where given an answer in your last posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960045/jpopupmenu-show-hide-toggle-not-working

Comment: It was only a comment, and a JWindow is usually used in the place of a JFrame. I've been trying to get a JWindow working but to no avail as of yet. It's not clutter if it's a fair question.

Comment: 1) Where is your SSCCE showing the code you used to try and get the JWindow working? We are not mind readers. We can't guess why you are having problems with a JWindow. 2) You posted your followup comment 9 minutes after you posted this question. How does anybody have time to answer your question in the other posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a JWindow or undecorated JDialog.

Comment: I'll figure out how to use a JWindow, thanks. Sorry for the clutter.

Comment: @paranoid-android  imaging that, so finally ....., don't forget look at link for JCalendar that I posted, there are 99,999999% workaround for Focus

Comment: curious: why the undecorated thingy? Typically, you either need the extended (vs. window) dialog/frame functionality or not. In the latter, use a JWindow. In the first case, the "decoration" (aka: handles to the functionality - one of my pet mis-nomers :-) is either provided by the the OS or by the LAF (but not left out altogether). What am I missing on early Monday morning?

Comment: @kleopatra `What am I missing on early Monday morning?` welcome to the > 10T users :-)

Comment: JWindow would normally be used. Just mentioned the dialog because you get parent/child behaviour. That is if you minimize the parent the child also minimizes. I Don't believe frame/window have this relationship.